# Export Semidefinite Program To MOSEK readible file

Tags: mathematical-optimization, export, file-transfer

Mathematica supports using the MOSEK solver for semidefinite programs now. I have some code that generates the conditions for some SDP problem, which I want to solve using MOSEK. Problem is that it needs a little more hardware than my computer with Mathematica can handle. Ideally I'd send my problem to some server, but the one I have access to with enough power only has Python.

I was wondering since both Mathematica and Python offer the possibility to solve SDP's using MOSEK whether I can export my SDP from Mathematica such that I can import it in Python and run it on a more powerful computer. Does anyone know if Mathematica generates some MOSEK readible file that you can export somewhere?

Best